# Is there a way to cherry pick Cloud Build runs with Github Comments?

Tags: github, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml, google-container-builder

I have set up my cloud build instances to only trigger when a comment of `/gcbrun` is made to the pull request.

I would like to be able to trigger specific, or all builds.

Currently using `/gcbrun` is triggering all of my builds when I would like to test out only one of them.